partially initialized module 'keras' has no attribute '__version__'
what should i do
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\pyfile\bert_for_ner\build_model.py", line 4, in 
from keras import backend as K
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras_init_.py", line 3, in 
from . import utils
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils_init_.py", line 26, in 
from .vis_utils import model_to_dot
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 7, in 
from ..models import Model
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 10, in 
from .engine.input_layer import Input
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine_init_.py", line 8, in 
from .training import Model
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 14, in 
from . import training_utils
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 17, in 
from .. import metrics as metrics_module
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 1850, in 
BaseMeanIoU = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 181, in getattr
self._initialize()
File "D:\python3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 149, in _initialize
if keras.version.startswith("3."):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'keras' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)
the whole code:
#! -- coding: utf-8 --
from keras import backend as K
class SetLearningRate:
"""
层的一个包装，用来设置当前层的学习率
"""
def init(self, layer, lamb, is_ada=False):
self.layer = layer
self.lamb = lamb # 学习率比例
self.is_ada = is_ada # 是否自适应学习率优化器
def __call__(self, inputs):
    with K.name_scope(self.layer.name):
        if not self.layer.built:
            input_shape = K.int_shape(inputs)
            self.layer.build(input_shape)
            self.layer.built = True
            if self.layer._initial_weights is not None:
                self.layer.set_weights(self.layer._initial_weights)
    for key in ['kernel', 'bias', 'embeddings', 'depthwise_kernel', 'pointwise_kernel', 'recurrent_kernel', 'gamma', 'beta']:
        if hasattr(self.layer, key):
            weight = getattr(self.layer, key)
            if self.is_ada:
                lamb = self.lamb # 自适应学习率优化器直接保持lamb比例
            else:
                lamb = self.lamb**0.5 # SGD（包括动量加速），lamb要开平方
            K.set_value(weight, K.eval(weight) / lamb) # 更改初始化
            setattr(self.layer, key, weight * lamb) # 按比例替换
    return self.layer(inputs)

def bert_bilstm_crf(config_path,checkpoint_path,num_labels,lstm_units,drop_rate,leraning_rate):
import keras
from bert4keras.models import build_transformer_model
from bert4keras.optimizers import Adam
from bert4keras.layers import ConditionalRandomField
bert = build_transformer_model(
config_path = config_path,
checkpoint_path = checkpoint_path,
model = 'albert',
return_keras_model = False # True，x = bert.output
)
x = bert.model.output # [batch_size, seq_length, 768]
lstm = SetLearningRate(
keras.layers.Bidirectional(
keras.layers.LSTM(
lstm_units,
kernel_initializer='he_normal',
return_sequences=True
)
),
500,
True
)(x) # [batch_size, seq_length, lstm_units * 2]
x = keras.layers.concatenate(
        [lstm,x],
        axis=-1
    ) # [batch_size, seq_length, lstm_units * 2 + 768]

x = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
        keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)
    )(x) # [batch_size, seq_length, lstm_units * 2 + 768]

x = SetLearningRate(
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
            keras.layers.Dense(
                    num_labels,
                    activation='relu',
                    kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                )
        ),
        500,
        True
    )(x) # [batch_size, seq_length, num_labels]

crf = ConditionalRandomField(lr_multiplier=500)
output = crf(x)

model = keras.models.Model(bert.input, output)
# model.summary()
model.compile(
        loss=crf.sparse_loss,
        optimizer=Adam(leraning_rate),
        metrics=[crf.sparse_accuracy]
    )

return model,crf

if name == 'main':
config_path = 'E:/pyfile/bert_for_ner/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = 'E:/pyfile/bert_for_ner/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model.ckpt'
num_labels = 21
lstm_units = 128
drop_rate = 0.1
leraning_rate = 5e-5
model , crf = bert_bilstm_crf(
config_path,checkpoint_path,num_labels,lstm_units,drop_rate,leraning_rate)
print(model.summary())
